# Using infinite scroll for load massive content without bug on Android App

Tags: java, php, android, jquery

Hello I have an application android, and I contact you having a problem. My application is a streaming application with a large number of works, the problem is that to load all works the load is really long, that's why I contact you I would like to use an infinite scroll but despite all Github projects i dont understand having low java base if you could tell me or place and how the necessary code thanks
This is my activity code :

```js
package com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.activities;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.Config;
import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.R;
import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.firebase.Analytics;
import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.fragments.FragmentAbout;
import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.fragments.FragmentFavorite;
import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.fragments.TabFragment;
import com.startapp.android.publish.Ad;
import com.startapp.android.publish.AdEventListener;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppAd;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppSDK;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    private AdView adView;
    private StartAppAd startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartAppSDK.init(this, getResources().getString(R.string.startapp_app_id), false);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Config.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Working in Normal Mode, RTL Mode is Disabled");
        }

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        firebaseAnalytics();

        loadAdMobBannerAd();

        loadStartAppWhenAppLaunch();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer);

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new TabFragment()).commit();

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                //setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_home) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new TabFragment()).commit();
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_favorite) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new FragmentFavorite()).commit();
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_rate) {
                    final String appName = getPackageName();
                    try {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appName)));
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appName)));
                    }
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_more) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.play_more_apps))));
                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.drawer_about) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new FragmentAbout()).commit();
                }

                return false;
            }

        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            loadStartAppOnBackPressed();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        adViewOnPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adViewOnResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        adViewOnDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void firebaseAnalytics() {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, getResources().getString(R.string.analytics_item_id_1));
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, getResources().getString(R.string.analytics_item_name_1));
        Analytics.getFirebaseAnalytics().logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
        Analytics.getFirebaseAnalytics().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
        Analytics.getFirebaseAnalytics().setMinimumSessionDuration(5000);
        Analytics.getFirebaseAnalytics().setSessionTimeoutDuration(1000000);

    }

    private void loadStartAppWhenAppLaunch() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_STARTAPP_ADS) {
            startAppAd.loadAd(new AdEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
                    startAppAd.showAd();
                    startAppAd.loadAd();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "StartApp When App Launch is Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void loadStartAppOnBackPressed() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_STARTAPP_ADS) {
            StartAppAd.onBackPressed(this);
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "StartApp onBackPressed is Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void loadAdMobBannerAd() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_ADS) {
            adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
                    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            Log.d("MainActivity", "AdMob Banner is Enabled");

        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "AdMob Banner is Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void adViewOnPause() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_ADS) {
            adView.pause();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "adView onPause is Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void adViewOnResume() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_ADS) {
            adView.resume();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "adView onResume is Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void adViewOnDestroy() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_ADS) {
            adView.destroy();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "adView onDestroy is Disabled");
        }
    }

}
```

and this is my adapter code :

```js
package com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.Config;
import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.R;
import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.activities.ActivityNewsDetail;
import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.json.JsonConfig;
import com.solodroid.androidnewsappdemo.models.ItemNewsList;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class AdapterNewsRecent extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterNewsRecent.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ItemNewsList> arrayItemNewsList;
    ItemNewsList itemNewsList;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView image;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView date;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
            date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_date);
            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

            if (Config.ENABLE_DATE_DISPLAY) {
                date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

    }

    public AdapterNewsRecent(Context context, List<ItemNewsList> arrayItemNewsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayItemNewsList = arrayItemNewsList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lsv_item_news_list, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        itemNewsList = arrayItemNewsList.get(position);

        Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        holder.title.setTypeface(font1);
        holder.date.setTypeface(font2);

        holder.title.setText(itemNewsList.getNewsHeading());
        holder.date.setText(itemNewsList.getNewsDate());

        Picasso.with(context).load(Config.SERVER_URL + "/upload/" +
                itemNewsList.getNewsImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail).into(holder.image);

        holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                itemNewsList = arrayItemNewsList.get(position);

                int pos = Integer.parseInt(itemNewsList.getCatId());

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityNewsDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("POSITION", pos);
                JsonConfig.NEWS_ITEMID = itemNewsList.getCatId();

                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayItemNewsList.size();
    }

}
```

I also have an API in php :

```html
<?php
 
    include_once ('includes/variables.php');
 
    $connect->set_charset('utf8');
   
    if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
    {      
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."' ORDER BY n.news_heading ASC";          
            $resouter = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
           
    }
   
    else if(isset($_GET['nid']))
    {      
            $id = $_GET['nid'];
 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid = n.cat_id && n.nid = '$id'";                   
            $resouter = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
           
    }  
   
    else if(isset($_GET['latest_news']))
    {
            $limit = $_GET['latest_news'];     
           
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE c.cid=n.cat_id ORDER BY n.news_heading ASC";          
            $resouter = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    }
 
    else
    {  
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category ORDER BY cid DESC";          
            $resouter = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    }
     
    $set = array();
     
    $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($resouter);
    if($total_records >= 1){
     
      while ($link = mysqli_fetch_array($resouter, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       
        $set['NewsApp'][] = $link;
      }
    }
     
    echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set));
     
?>
```

My problem is on the "else if(isset($_GET['latest_news']))"

Thanks for help

Comment: It's a nice thought, but "I am ready to pay you" isn't how we do things here.

Comment: sorry i'm french bad traduction it's a present and not just a purchase but sorry...

Comment: No worries, just letting you know.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener ?
You can found it here : https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e

This way you could implement paging and you will not load all your stuff the first time you launch your activity.

You have to define a Step. It will be the number of items you will load per page. You will define it, backend (php API) and  frontend (Android App).

**Backend**

1. You have to add a new parameter on your php API like this :

   isset($_GET['page'])
2. Then your SQL query will look like this :

   $page = $_GET['page'];
   $step = 5;

   $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_news_category c,tbl_news n WHERE     c.cid=n.cat_id and c.cid='".$_GET['cat_id']."' ORDER BY n.news_heading ASC LIMIT ".(($page - 1) * $step) . "," . $step;

**Android App**

Get the EndlessRecyclerOnScollListener.

Add a private int current_page to your class.

Add a Scroll Listener on your RecyclerView like this :

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(
new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())) {
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore() {
                    CallPhpApi(cat_id, current_page);
                }
            });
```

In the CallPhpApi, just call your php API with your new parameter page.
Get your objects from your request and add them to you arrayItemNewsList. Then notify your adapter that dataset changed by calling :

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help but i'm strong in php but not in java i have finish my api.php but i don't understand what i have to do on my android app, i add the EndlessRecyclerOnScollListener.java on my projet i create a private int current_page on my class on activity without value ? and i add your code, sorry i don't understand i'm french and i'm not strong on java, do you have an email i can send you the projet if you want ?

Comment: Send me a email : orlanth23@hotmail.com

Comment: i have sent 2 mails